# Typescript error on function wrapper: number[] is not assignable to [number]

Tags: typescript

Here is code, the function require two arguments: one is the function need to wrap, one is the argument producer

```js
function wrapper<K extends Array<any>, T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T {
  return fn(...pd());
}

wrapper((id: number) => id, (id: number) => {
  return [id];
})
```

But there is an error in the producer function declaration:

```
Argument of type '(id: number) => number[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: any) => [id: number]'.
  Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[id: number]'.
    Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.(2345)
```

How can I fix this error and not modify the function struct? Thank!

[Here is the playground code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8A0ojgB5Q5gAmAzogIKoYCe+6YzAfADSIAqnABTAwALkSCAdNPSoA5jXGEAlIgC8nfr0xVxUmfMWJ2zVRsQrxfRAG8AUIkSocUEKiQj9knYOXKA3HYAvnZ2aFi4qIKCMLqIYCAAtgBGeGaasbwxcQkpaeqa9o7Oru6IANqxALqBQcpAA)

Comment: There's a more basic issue: The example argument producer function expects parameters (`id` and `iq`) and used one of them (`id`), but `wrapper` doesn't pass any arguments to it at all (`...pd()`). Where are the arguments for the argument producer's parameters supposed to come from?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Opps, sorry that I was an oversight, I forgot to remove iq when writing the example from the code, it has been updated and the problem still exists.
The parameters of the wrapper are generated by the deduction to the generic definition,

Comment: @T.J.Crowder By the way, this is just a minimal reproducible demo, in fact the `wrapper` will do a lot more about parameter handling, but it's not important to the issue, so here's the simplest example.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Or maybe my description is wrong, what I'm trying to complete shouldn't be called a wrapper, but none of that affects the bug that is generated in this question, the code is there after all.

Comment: Again, though, the function you're passing for `pd` expects an argument (`id`), but `wrapper` calls it with no arguments (`return fn(...pd());`). Ignore the type issue for a second, that just doesn't work at a runtime / logic level.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I found some solutions:

using type infer:

```
function wrapper<K extends Function>(fn: K, pd: K extends (...args: infer P) => any ? (...args: any) => P : never): K extends (...args: any[]) => infer T ? T : never {
  return fn(...pd());
}

wrapper((id: number) => id, (id: number) => {
  return [id]
})

wrapper((id: string) => id, (id: string) => {
  return [id]
})

wrapper((id: bigint, id2: string) => id, (id: bigint, id2: string) => {
  return [id, id2]
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8A0ojgB5Q5gAmAzogGLjTxgB8AFMGAFyKEA0iTFV7EyFanXYA6WelQBzGrxhhgeRAAUAlIgC8rROjABPRAH5EMuYuVHTug1sS8wOAG55tokuUq0rWWl5JV5jEwBtAF1HQ1V1VEQAFQtkl0Q3T0SAbwAoRERUHCgQVCQua2lhdm1tAG5cgF9c3LQsXFR2dhgRDJAAWwAjL304qkFu3rAB4dRYxDyCopKyxAieqKbtFrbsPC6e3hooVFUFeZ6Jw8Rj07Bz0YX8wuLSpHWqTcbt1ow9zsmvEGMAUqiggh6ACYjiczhdxlZrsDQWBwYgoTC7g8nIsXit3pd0VRIV9tEA)

using ramda, enum all the arguments:

```
function wrapper<A1, K extends [A1], T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T;
function wrapper<A1, A2, K extends [A1, A2], T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T;
function wrapper<A1, A2, A3, K extends [A1, A2, A3], T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T;
function wrapper<A1, A2, A3, A4, K extends [A1, A2, A3, A4], T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T;
function wrapper<A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, K extends [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5], T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T;
function wrapper<K extends Array<any>, T>(fn: (...args: K) => T, pd: (...args: any) => K): T {
  return fn(...pd());
}

wrapper((id: number, a: string) => id, (id: number) => {
  return [id, '12'];
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AggIwA0iA0ojgB5Q5gAmAzogNokC65AKgHwAKYGABciAQDop6VAHNmYigEpEAXj6Ie5TIzGTpchYnRgAnivWUlYngG4AUKEiwEKDNjxEyiQgCZyVLT0TKwc3n7cmoLCelISMvKKFhpaiDqxBonGZslWNg5O0PBIaFi4BCTkflUAzAHUdAws7JU%20-j41kfxCouJxCUbKainaun2ZRibmw3maBeBFrqUeFeHthHU%20ACz1QU2hrdUdVVtd0b368YZJM6np41dZU7nK%20Y4LLiXu5V5V65uEHY%20ACsu0aIRaa1qJyqwLOPQyj0GuTuY0uAzEzxmrzm72cxTcZU8gXBzUIqAwpnwUz4vHOiIxVluowZ12y00sOJ4iAA3vZEIhUDgoCBUEhhJcdAIlEoHABfez2ZblAQCGBjMAgAC2ACM8OR0GJmFBUDAwLJcuryGqNdq9ahcnyBUKRWL2FbEAByYi%20T2ceVKIA)

If there are more solutions, let's discuss them!

Comment: That may have worked around the type issues, but the code doesn't work, for the reasons [I mentioned yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72938654/typescript-error-on-function-wrapper-number-is-not-assignable-to-number#comment128827758_72938654). Click "Run" in [this version of your playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXQ8ON) where I've just added a `console.log` on the return value. `wrapper` returns `undefined`, because `fn` returns `undefined`, because `pd` is called with no arguments, so it returns `[undefined, undefined]`, calling `fn` with `undefined, undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, I finally got your point. Sorry for an unreasonable example. But really I only wanted to talk about type inference, not what the function actually does, so I didn't verify the usability of the code, and the minimum reproducibility was limited to the type system.

Comment: Respectfully, it matters that the implementation doesn't make any sense. It makes it next to impossible to suss out what you're really trying to do and help you do it, and next to impossible for others coming to the question later to get any benefit from it.